# Why Python fatal error occurs after OpenCV build?

Tags: python, opencv

I've built OpenCV 4.5.5 on Windows with Cmake / VS19. I did PATH and copy&paste .pyd file as well. Now I am getting the Fatal Python error, I have no clue what is the problem.

> Fatal Python error: _PyInterpreterState_GET: the function must be called with the GIL held, but the GIL is released (the current Python thread state is NULL)
> Python runtime state: unknown

The reason I built opencv myself was to use some library I wanted to use which requires the Nonfree OpenCV module. So I removed the OpenCV package which I installed by `pip install opencv-python`. Then I followed Cmake build instructions with OpenCV/OpenCV-contrib source. Is there any possibility that I installed the OpenCV module before?

I've tried to modify / repair Python but no luck. When I import other library (for example : Numpy) it works fine. Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: Can you show us your Cmake config ?